# Replacing (not upgrading) Ubuntu 12.04.5 with 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, downgrade

I have a new laptop. I have dual booted it with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu by installing Ubuntu 12.04.5. I don't have any data on the Ubuntu side and can format it. I want to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04.5 completely and recreate a dual boot by installing Ubuntu 14.04. I do NOT want to upgrade; rather, I want to freshly install Ubuntu 14.04.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy, just boot the 14.04 installation media, choose install, select the linux partitions and mark format in the parttition manager.

Comment: Thank you. How about the entries in \EFI\Boot directory. What should I do with boot files generated by Ubuntu 12.04.5 in the \EFI\Boot directory? Doesn't it need to restore MBR file?